# Crash on Android 2.3.3 after upgrading to support library 25.0.0 (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.isAttachedToWindow)

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

After upgrading to the latest version of the support library, I'm no longer able to run the app on Android 2.3.3. The app crashes during startup with the

> 11-01 13:53:16.580 2115-2115/no.bouvet.routeplanner.atb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.isAttachedToWindow
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ForwardingListener$2.(ForwardingListener.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ForwardingListener.addDetachListenerBase(ForwardingListener.java:101)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ForwardingListener.(ForwardingListener.java:78)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton$1.(ActionMenuPresenter.java:650)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton.(ActionMenuPresenter.java:650)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.initForMenu(ActionMenuPresenter.java:114)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.addMenuPresenter(MenuBuilder.java:262)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.getMenu(ActionMenuView.java:656)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.ensureMenu(Toolbar.java:1037)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getMenu(Toolbar.java:1008)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.getMenu(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:676)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.getMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:595)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:447)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The dependencies used are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

The error disappears of I downgrade to 24.2.2, but this causes other problems (when using the default android searchview, the text that the user enters is not visible, even though the autocomplete works fine)

I assume this is a bug in the support library. Have anyone seen the same problem and know of a fix?

Comment: I tried to downgrade to 23.4.0 but the error has not disappear.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the support library. I had a similar problem, changed my dependency to older appcompat 23.4.0 and design 23.4.0 and it works OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue with Support Library 25.0.0:https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225647.
You can reproduce the issue by creating a new project and using the standard `Basic Activity` template in Android Studio. The app will crash on `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` on devices API 11 and below.
I didn't find another solution except to downgrade support library version.

Comment: It was resolved in 25.0.1: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved with new realease:
Android Support Library, revision 25.0.1 (November 2016)
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html